# output of Array is not working as expected

Tags: python, arrays

my code was working fine until i wanted to output the highest score from my Tscore array with the name of the student with the highest score.all my program does now is output the first score only. Please help!

```
Name=[]
Test1=[]
Test2=[]
Test3=[]
Tscore=[]
sum=0
for i in range(3):
    validinput1= False
    validinput2= False
    validinput3= False
    sname=input("Enter your name:")
    while not validinput1:
        test1=int(input("Enter your score for test 1:"))
        if test1<0 or test1>20:
            print("Invalid input")
        else:
            validinput1= True
     while not validinput2:
        test2=int(input("Enter your score for test 2:"))
        if test2<0 or test2>25:
            print("Invalid input")
        else:
            validinput2= True
     while not validinput3:
        test3=int(input("Enter your score for test 3:"))
        if test3<0 or test3>35:
            print("Invalid input")
        else:
            validinput3= True
    total=test1+test2+test3
    Name.append(sname)
    Test1.append(test1)
    Test2.append(test2)
    Test3.append(test3)
    Tscore.append(total)    
    sum=sum+total
avg=sum/3
for i in range(3):
    print(Name[i]," total score: ", Tscore[i])
    print(Name[i],"got the highest score: ", max(Tscore[i]))
print("The average of the class is: ", avg)
```

I would like to print the name and total score of all 3 students, then output the class average of all students and then the highest score with the students name.

Comment: `max(Tscore[i])` returns the highest of a single value which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: For starters, please format your code and reduce it to the _minimal_ example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `max(Tscore)` and **NOT** `max(Tscore[i])` to find max value of a list.

```
print(Name[i],"got the highest score: ", max(Tscore))
```

Comment: Did it work for you?? And are you getting now what you expected??

Comment: no it did not work correctly  it gives me the first input name and then the max score which is not right because if the last student inputted received the highest mark it will print that mark and the name of the first student

Comment: @ImaaniSmile, But I tried this program and it is working fine, just try it once again after modification.

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue, this is my result from running the program Enter your name:t
Enter your score for test 1:6
Enter your score for test 2:6
Enter your score for test 3:6
g  total score:  21
e  total score:  12
t  total score:  18
The average of the class is:  17.0
t got the highest score:  21